# How can I use a dredd docker image interactively?

Tags: docker, dredd

I would like to use this docker container [apiaryio/dredd](https://hub.docker.com/r/apiaryio/dredd/) instead of the [npm package `dredd`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dredd). I am not familiar with running and debugging npm based docker images. How can I run the basic usage example of the [npm package "Quick Start" section](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dredd#quick-start)

```
$ dredd init
$ dredd
```

if I have a Swagger file instead of the `api-description.apib` in `$PWD/api/api.yaml` or `$PWD/api/api.json`?

Comment: I've tried to improve the docs: https://dredd.org/en/latest/installation.html#docker

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR

Run dredd image as a command line. [Dredd Image at Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/r/apiaryio/dredd/)

```
docker run -it -v $PWD:/api -w /api apiaryio/dredd init
```

[Optional] Turn it into a script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo '***'
echo 'Root dir is /api'
export MYIP=`ifconfig | sed -En 's/127.0.0.1//;s/.*inet (addr:)?(([0-9]*\.){3}[0-9]*).*/\2/p'`
echo 'Host ip is: ' $MYIP
echo 'Configure URL of tested API endpoint: http://api-srv::<enpoint-port>. Set api-srv to point to your server.'
echo 'This script will set api-srv to docker host machine - ' $MYIP
echo '***'

docker run -it --add-host "api-srv:$MYIP" -v $PWD:/api -w /api apiaryio/dredd dredd $1
```

[Optional] And put this script in a folder that is in your PATH variable and create an alias for short it

```
alias dredd='bash ./scripts/dredd.sh'
```

Code at [Github gist](https://gist.github.com/asantos2000/9043e7466d873bf4bd46a57651ccc1c3).

Comment: I've tried to improve the docs: https://dredd.org/en/latest/installation.html#docker